# Send messages from client to server

Tags: java, server, client

I'm having problems sending messages from client to server and to server to other clients. Please can you give me a hand by telling me something.
The problem is if I do an input (line 46) I can get an answer from the server (line 51) then continue this loop.
But for example, if the server must notify a user that it's his turn, I wouldn't get the message until I try typing something.

```java
while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
    /* line 46 */ out.println(userInput);
    if (userInput.equals("quit")) {
        break;
    }

    /* line 51 */ lines = in.readLine();
    System.out.println(lines);

    System.out.println("input next command:");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make (at least i dont know how else to do it) a separate thread where you get user input, then use message passing (just search "message passing java") for comunication. Server messages will not get blocked by input and you can `tryReceive` (or some name around that lines) on channel. In main thread query for message from server, then from input channel, sleep a little and repeat. When user presses enter, channel gets filled with his message, main thread takes it when passing by.